# C socket server send same message to all clients

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to send the same message to all connected clients over C sockets. Server is working as expected but I want to send the server command line input to all clients and display at their end. Here is the code I am using ;

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int opt = TRUE;
    int master_socket , addrlen , new_socket , client_socket[30] ,
        max_clients = 30 , activity, i , valread , sd, sd_new;
    int max_sd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
        
    char buffer[102500]; //data buffer of 1K

    std::string(bufc) = "";
    std::string last_send = "";
    
    //set of socket descriptors
    fd_set readfds;
        
    //a message
    //char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";
    
    //initialise all client_socket[] to 0 so not checked
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }
        
    //create a master socket
    if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    //set master socket to allow multiple connections ,
    //this is just a good habit, it will work without this
    if( setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt,
        sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    //type of socket created
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
        
    //bind the socket to localhost port 8888
    if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Listener on port %d \n", PORT);
        
    //try to specify maximum of 3 pending connections for the master socket
    if (listen(master_socket, 10) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        
    //accept the incoming connection
    addrlen = sizeof(address);
    puts("Waiting for connections ...");
        
    while(TRUE)
    {
        /*
*/
        
        //clear the socket set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    
        //add master socket to set
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;
            
        //add child sockets to set
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++)
        {
            //socket descriptor
            sd = client_socket[i];
                
            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
            if(sd > 0)
                FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
                
            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
            if(sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }
    
        //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL ,
        //so wait indefinitely
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);
    
        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR))
        {
            printf("select error");
        }
            
        //If something happened on the master socket ,
        //then its an incoming connection
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds))
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket,
                    (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
            {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            
            //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
            printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d\n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
        
                
            //add new socket to array of sockets
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
            {
                //if position is empty
                if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                {
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                    printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }



        //else its some IO operation on some other socket
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++)
        {
            sd = client_socket[i];

            if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds))
            {
                //Check if it was for closing , and also read the
                //incoming message
                if ((valread = read( sd , buffer, 102400)) == 0)
                {
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , \
                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                    printf("Host disconnected , ip %s , port %d \n" ,
                        inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));

                    close( sd );
                    client_socket[i] = 0;
                }

                else
                {
                    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , \
                        (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                    printf("From client ip %s , port %d , %s\n" ,
                        inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port), buffer);
                    buffer[valread] = '\0';
                    std::string(bufc) = buffer;
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    char semi = ':';
                    
                    if(bufc[0] == semi){
                    std::string newString(bufc.substr(1));
                    sd_new = sd;
                    
                     for ( int client= 0 ; client < max_clients ; client++)
                    {
                        sd_test = client_socket[client];
                        if (sd_test != sd_new)
                        {
                        send(sd_test , newString.c_str() , strlen(newString.c_str()) , 0 );
                        }
                    }
                
                }
                
                else{
                    last_send += bufc + "\n";
                    }
            }
        }
        
    }
    send(sd_new , last_send.c_str() , strlen(last_send.c_str()) , 0 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the guide of comments I was able to send to all connected clients and read back their response. Now the issue is I am facing a SIGPIPE Pipe Broken for one of the send commands I don't know which one and where ?

Comment: Use a `for` loop that loops over the array of client sockets and sends the message to each.

Comment: How do your clients know how long the message sent is?  TCP connections are *streams*, where there are no boundaries between what gets written to the stream.  And what happens if your `read()` call *fails*?

Comment: OT: `0` is a valid file descriptor, use `-1` to indicate invalid / not set. Also `socket` returns `-1` on error and not `0`.

Comment: You have to tell the server to send the input to all connected clients.

Comment: To add to @AndrewHenle remark: also `send()` can fail, or hang indefinitely for blocking sockets. Note that `read()` and `send()` returning less than the number of bytes of the message is not necessarily an error; partial reads/writes are normal and you should handle them correctly in your code.